# Open link on clicking dynamic objects in a list

Tags: jquery, onclick, handlebars.js, dynamic-list

I have a code in Handlebars that generates dynamic list.

```
<ul id="expList">
{{#each hierarchy}}
    <li class="index">{{@key}}
        <ul>
            {{#each this}}
                <li class="country">{{@key}}
                    <ul>
                        {{#each this}}
                            <li class="cluster">{{@key}}
                                <ul>
                                    {{#each this}}
                                        <li class="farm">{{@key}}
                                        </li>
                                    {{/each}}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Now i want a webpage to open when i click an element. The URL will be a combination of the element clicked and its parent.

Without having an id because of being dynamic, how should i attach an onClick event in jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on()` : http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("click", ".cluster", function(e) {
   // you can get your clicked element here
   console.log("event"); 
});
```

**EDIT**

So for a farm :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("click", ".farm", function(e) {
     var idfarm= $(this).attr('data-id');
     var idcluster= $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-id');
     
     $("#result").html(idfarm +"|"+ idcluster);
     console.log("event"); 
     
     // This cant work in stackoverflow sandbox allow-popups permission is not set
     window.open('http://localhost:8000?farm='+idfarm+'&cluster='+idcluster,'GoogleWindow', 'width=800, height=600');
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="cluster" data-id="key cluster">key cluster
     <ul>      
       <li class="farm" data-id="key farm">Key farm</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I understood that in a crude way. Can you please elaborate it a little bit with the help of a sample code?

Comment: On which element would you add the click event ? I can make a complete exemple but I need to have some informations.

Comment: Suppose i select a farm, then it should open an url like -->>localhost:3000/?index=(selectedindex)&country=(selectedcountry)&cluster=(selectedcluster)&farm=(selectedfarm).  And when the page reloads with this information, i need to retain the selected fields. As in, the list shouldn't reset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question though. What is the 'data-id' field??? How do you assign that  value in data-id? Because the list is being generated dynamically.

Comment: You should change your handlebars template like that for exemple for country : `<li data-id="{{@key}}" class="country">{{@key}}</li>`. `data-id` is a custom attribute, it's simpler to get it than get the `innerHtml` of your element. More infos about data attributes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't seem to be working. I did something like this.

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("click", ".farm", function(e) {
     var idfarm= $(this).attr('value');
     alert(idfarm);
     });
});
</script>

Comment: Doesn't give me the name of the farm when i click it.

Comment: Its because your farm doesnt have attribute 'value'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105825/discussion-between-nikhil-tikoo-and-quentin-roger).

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks a ton for being so patient with me. :)